# What's the minimum distance between two iron golem farms?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Considering the pretty common design (20x20 base) for the iron golem farms, what is the minimum distance from one golem farm to another to make them work correctly? And how is this "distance" calculated diagonally?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

The centers are 63.639 blocks apart (from vector [0, 0, 0] to vector [45, 0, 45] as [x, y, z]) and they are read as two separate village.

Comment: 64 blocks diagonally is was more than 64 blocks horizontally, so yeah that was pretty obvious. I was wondering what is the minimum diagonally.

Comment: (x,y,z)0,0,0 -> 45,0,45 = 63.639 blocks, rounds up to 64.  I phrased it wrong above.

Comment: Does having the second one at [44,0,45] cause it to no longer work as two separate villages?

Answer (score 7):

There is a good write up on Village mechanics on the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Village_mechanics#Overlapping_boundaries). For two villages to be safely treated as separate villages, they need to be greater than **radius + 32** blocks away from each other.

Not that the radius is defined as:

- The distance from the center point to the furthest door, -OR-
- 32 blocks

whichever is *greater*. This means that the radius is **always at least 32**, no matter what, but it can be more than that if there are any houses further than 32 blocks from the center

So, if your Iron Golem farms are **20x20**, and the center of the village is slap bang in the middle of that, then your radius is a **further 10 blocks** from one side of the farm, (i.e. **30 blocks**). However, 30 < 32, so we take radius=32

radius + 32 = (32) + 32 = **64 blocks**.

If you are working a lot with villages/golem farms, you might find this mod handy: [Village Info Mod](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1077712-162forgesspsmp-village-info/). It will help calculate how far you are from the village center, and other useful info.

Comment: Good answer but you didn't explained well (actually not at all) the diagonally problem. How is the distance calculated diagonally (which is the answer that interested me the most in the first place)?. I don't recall reading about it in the wiki and the whole point of this question is not to test that by myself.

Comment: This answer needs an update for newer MC versions

Answer (score 1):

Straight from the 1.14 code:

```
protected int villageDistance = 32;
```

And

```
protected final int villageSeparation = 8;
```

Though I don't think distance is checked in later versions.

From what I've seen, the requirements to spawn it is:

1. The villager must be gossiping with another villager
2. The villager has NOT recently slept AND worked
3. The villager has not seen an iron golem recently
4. The villager has a profession
5. 5 villagers within 10 blocks meet those requirements (other than #1).

This is from the yarn deobfusication of Minecraft, I don't see any other requirements in the code.

Comment: Could you add a bit more information? What do those numbers represent? What are those distances measured from? And how to they impact the Iron golem spawning algorithm?

Comment: @zeel What I'm saying is I don't think they do, all I could find is arbitrary values but I don't really think they affect Iron Golem spawning, just the requirements I outlined.

Comment: Then, based on imperial observation, how much separation is needed to prevent interference? The question is "what's the minimum distance between farms" and that still needs settled.

Comment: From what I've seen, as long as you block line of sight from iron golems and have 5+ villagers with professions out of sight Iron Golems should spawn.  It shouldn't interfere in the first place.

Comment: So you are saying that there is no actual distance requirement now, as long as the villagers can't see another golem, they will still create their own?

Comment: That is what I am seeing in the code, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Robotnik gives some quite advanced calculations but the simple answer is a door will generate a new village if it's registered more than 64 blocks (euclidean) away from the nearest registered door of an existing village.

After a new village is registered, another door can be registered belonging to it, lying even adjacent to previous door, making the villages overlap and their centers to be a block apart, but unless you want to perform mind-boggling wizardry like the [Iron Trench](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YFaCNsuD01k) to force order of registering doors, just make sure there is at least 64 blocks gap between doors of one farm and doors of the other.

Answer (score 0):

It is 100 blocks away from each iron golem farm but it is 150 block from each village.

Comment: Could you add some detail and supporting evidence? Where do those numbers come from?

Answer (score -1):

Tango Tek stated the distance formula and said all calculations suggest a min. distance of 150 blocks of distance between the iron farm and any villages and a distance of 100  blocks between two iron farms. this is to keep the golems spawning in the farms and not inbetween them.....I have used his calculations on my own world and find them to be accurate as between my two farms I am cranking out 3500 - 5000 iron in an hour. both my farms drop into a killing chamber lined with hoppers the iron is transported to the automatic storage and the poppies are shot into a nether portal.   the valid distance between 2 villages is 68.5 blocks or 69 since half blocks dont stack sideways.

Answer (score -2):

In an Iron Golem farming tutorial, for maximum yield it prescribed a 256 block separation. This tutorial was by docm and located on youtube:

The 256 block gap is not required; it just provides maximum yield.

Comment: Which tutorial? Do you have a link to the Youtube video?

Comment: @Coronus http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=xE04Ui90sQY&desktop_uri=%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DxE04Ui90sQY

Comment: I would put the link in the answer, and if the tutorial explains why the 256 blocks are necessary, that would be helpful information to include.

Comment: @Coronus Okay :)

Answer (score -2):

On The Wiki It Says it's 66 Blocks minium distance.