# Village Validation Distance Criteria

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Quick question, but I was wondering why my villager breeder isn't working, and I *may* have found a reason. My villager breeder is <64-or-so blocks required away from my iron farm, **but** my iron farm is high in the sky, making it more than 64 blocks away. I know that euclidean distance is calculated for this stuff ([What's the minimum distance between two iron golem farms?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/128278/whats-the-minimum-distance-between-two-iron-golem-farms)), but is that only for the X and Z coordinates? So my here's my question: "Is height calculated into making villages valid?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Villages are spherical, the size is determined by a radius around the village center (which doesn't have to be the well in generated villages).